# My Highscore amount keeps going up and down. Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a spritekit game which I have a highscore in. It uses NSUser Default. But I get the highscore 2, and then I close the app completely, and then open it it shows my highscore 2, and then get one as a score. It remains as 2. However, I close the app again and open it, it shows the highscore 1. Why does it do this? This is my code. Does the if condition not work? Note: This is just narrowed down to Highscore code.

```
import SpriteKit

//In the DidMoveToView function
if let Highscore1 = defaults.stringForKey("Highscore"){
    HighScoreLabel.text = "HIGHSCORE: \(Highscore1)"
}
//In the touches began func
//Making what happens when the User Fails and a new highscore is achieved

if Score > highscore {

    defaults.setObject("\(Score)", forKey: "Highscore")

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't recall if you need to do this in iOS8, but just in case, is synchronize being called anywhere? Perhaps add it right after setObject to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are reading the highscore from `NSUserDefaults` and showing it in the `HighScoreLabel`. But you didn't assigned/stored the value in `highscore` variable, because of that it remains at 0. That makes the following condition true when you open the app and plays for the first time:

```
if Score > highscore {
    defaults.setObject("\(Score)", forKey: "Highscore")
}
```

You need to change the high score reading part like:

```
if let Highscore1 = defaults.stringForKey("Highscore") {
    HighScoreLabel.text = "HIGHSCORE: \(Highscore1)"

    // Storing current high score to variable
    highscore           = Int(Highscore1)
}
```